# j2me Execution failed with error code 1, CLDC-run

Tags: netbeans, java-me, cldc

I've made an j2me application in NetBeans 7.1 with both j2me SDK 3.0 and 3.0.5. A few days ago, before a major change in code which doesn't affect the startup, it ran fine. When trying to run the app now it starts the emulator, but fails to start the app. The output is showing the following:

```
Starting emulator in execution mode
Installing suite from: http://127.0.0.1:16200/BuitenBeter.jad
Processing UPDATE_CLASS
```

Upon closing the emulator the following error shows:

```
*** Error ***
Failed to execute MIDlet suite
C:\Users\Willem\Documents\NetBeansProjects\BuitenBeter\nbproject\build-impl.xml:782: Execution failed with error code 1.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 minute 16 seconds)
```

The xml it's pointing to is:

```
<!--cldc-run-->
<target name="cldc-run" if="cldc-platform.trigger">
    <nb-run jadfile="${dist.dir}/${dist.jad}" jarfile="${dist.dir}/${dist.jar}" jadurl="${dist.jad.url}" device="${platform.device}" platformhome="${platform.home}" platformtype="${platform.type}" execmethod="${run.method}" securitydomain="${evaluated.run.security.domain}" commandline="${platform.runcommandline}" classpath="${platform.bootclasspath}:${dist.dir}/${dist.jar}" cmdoptions="${run.cmd.options}"/>
</target>
```

So I'm assuming that the CLDC fails to run.

When I created an empty new project with just the "Hello World" code in it, it runs fine with the same configuration. Which is:

- j2me SDK 3.0.5
- DefaultCldcPhone1
- CLDC-1.1
- MIDP-2.0
- All the optional Packages selected

I've tried with SDK 3.0, I've tried without all optional packages, I've tried using CLDC-1.1.1. But when selecting CLDC-1.1.1 it automaticly does the following:

```
Platform UEI-1.0.1 does not support "CLDC-1.1.1" configuration, setting back to CLDC-1.1.
```

So far after Googling I've tried the following sollutions:

- Simply restart NetBeans
- Stopping Windows Firewall
- Using different devices and configurations

Can anyone tell me what's wrong or what I can do to fix this?

Comment: Did you solved it? I have the same problem using the default demo project: HelloMidlet.java

Comment: @Memochipan nope, I've found a work around by importing the project in the J2ME SKD 3.0 which still runs on my laptop. It's not a solution, but it works :)

Answer (score 0):

Downloading the lastest version seemed to fix this problem for me. I am running
 - Product Version: NetBeans IDE 7.2 (Build 201207171143)
 - Java: 1.7.0_03; Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM 22.1-b02

and this is now working fine. Unfortunately netbeans update functionality did not work so you will need to un-install your current netbeans, download and install a new instance.